# How to find all keys used in NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation, nscoding

I have an NSData that was created by using `NSKeyedArchiver`. Is there a way to iterate over all the values inside it? It must somehow be possible to get all the keys that were stored in it when using `+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]`.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do that. Depending on the use case, you might want to encode and decode a dictionary object.

Answer (score 1):

A NSKeyedArchived file "simply" is a property list. You would need to find out the structure of that plist, though.

I found the source code of Cocotron very helpful one day, as I tried to decode some NSKeyedUnarchived data: http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSKeyedArchiving/NSKeyedUnarchiver.m (Maybe look at line 39 (initForReadingWithData:) which is called by unarchiveObjectWithData: (line #164)).

Maybe you can find out more about the archived objects that way.